# Windows Explorer not automatically refreshing after renaming or deletion

Tags: windows, refresh, explorer

For some reason, in Windows 11, it feels like after:

- Creating a folder
- Renaming a folder/file
- Deleting a folder/file

A lot of the time (unsure about exact parameters) Windows Explorer just won't refresh until I hit "F5" to manually update the view.

This is leading to a lot of "the file or folder you are trying to access is no longer present" type of error messages and overall annoyance with the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that in my and apparently many other cases, having a **network location  (that may or may not be accessible) in the "Quick Access"** is causing the lack of automatic refreshes.

In my case, all I had to do was right-clicking the offending entries and selecting "Unpin from Quick Access".

This is as answered [here](https://www.surfacetablethelp.com/2022/05/windows-11-folders-not-refreshing-automatically-in-file-explorer.html).

[This article describes all about setting up Quick Access to your liking.](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/customize-quick-access-folders-in-windows-11/)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, and something else I found that causes this is the OneDrive folder that seems to be the default for Documents and Pictures (and Desktop) in Windows 11 (C:\Users<username>\OneDrive). If you turn off automatic OneDrive sync, as I have done, this also causes the Windows Explorer refresh issue.
I've resorted to not using those folders for anything